# how to track where my php file is running

Tags: php

i am not a professional coder so that,s why asking you for a ready made code or solution actually i want to track my php file that where it is being used because many peoples use our php project file on different websites so i want to track the php web file with its location that where my php file is being used.

i want my php file to send me its location in my email like if the php file is running at www.example.com/php/abc.php it sends me the url of where it is running.

Or any suggestion to track my php file would be helpful.

Comment: If you didn't ship your code with something that "phones home" (which, if your code did that, I would never use it), then it will be pretty much impossible to do what you wish. What were your licensing terms? How about the terms of service? Does it mention you want to spy on others' servers?

Comment: @Ahmed Mehtab Sorry Bro, you dont have any solution for search server script, If it is an HTML output we can search!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a server which will get this information
and will have to add more code to your existing code:

```
@file_get_content('http://www.yourserver.com?filelocation='.__FILE__.'&host='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

and then on http://www.yourserver.com you will have to catch this code

```
mail('you@yourserver.com','code running from: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'host: '.$_GET['host'].' file path: '.$_GET['filelocation']);
```

This is what you basically have to do but I am sure it will pist of some of your users
and I hope you have good goals

Answer (score 0):

I read this topic with care and finally I understand that what you want. You simply want to hack someone's website for different purposes. You are now able to access any server if some one put your php file in their server.

right?

If you say that I am wrong then I will just say that no php project developer ask this stupid question because developers can develop this tracking script with some easy steps.

By the way I give you an idea that will help you. Use only if you want not to hack any website.

ONLY FOR SIMPLE beginner PHP PROJECT DEVELOEPRS.
SIMPLY Develop an automated email sending coding (php mail) in your php script. This will keep track your php files location by sending you exact location in email.

This is just a simple option if you are not advanced php script developer.

Hints:

@file_get_content('http://www.yourserver.com?filelocation='.**FILE**.'&host='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

AND:

mail('you@yourserver.com','code running from: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'host: '.$_GET['host'].' file path: '.$_GET['filelocation']);

Comment: If you believe the OP is asking for help in doing something malicious the correct thing to do would be to flag the question. I see no evidence of that in the question (but I am far from a php expert!). You should restrict your answer to addressing the question and, by all means, if you have concerns about the question flag it.